# what does the order_qs[0] do in the following code, also can someone explain the following code to me

Tags: django, django-views

I am doing a project and have referred to someone else's code. But I am not able to understand the part after order_qs. can someone please it to me.
There are some lines/functions that I am not able to understand.

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.orderitems.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return redirect("mainapp:home")
        else:
            order.orderitems.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
            return redirect("mainapp:home")
    else:
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user)
        order.orderitems.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
        return redirect("mainapp:home")
```

Models.py file:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.quantity} 0f {self.product.name}'
    
    
class Order(models.Model):
    orderitems = models.ManyToManyField(Cart)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __Str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: share the corresponding models.

Comment: I have added the models

Answer (score 0):

It will return the *first* item of the `order_qs`, we know that this exists, because we first check it exists, but it is quite inefficient, since we first check if it exists, and then make another query, it is even (slightly) sensitive to *race conditions*, a more effective way is likely:

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(item=item, user=request.user)
    order, __ = Order.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    # check if the order item is in the order
    if order.orderitems.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
        order_item.quantity += 1
        order_item.save()
        messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
        return redirect("mainapp:home")
    else:
        order.orderitems.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
        return redirect("mainapp:home")
```

although this is likely still far from optimal, but the modeling looks quite strange anyway.